# Where can I find visible/radio telescopic observations of the center of the Milky Way galaxy?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, specific-reference, milky-way

I recently stumbled across this time-lapse telescopic image (radio image, I believe) of the center of the galaxy.

Here's a still image. Link to time-lapse video below.
[image]

I haven't been able to find this image anywhere else.
My only source is this obscure YouTube link (timestamp included, to make it easier for you)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dk2-lH9ewuA&t=143

I don't recall ever seeing this image in the past, and I'm interested to know where it came from.

Is there any publicly-available research around these observations?

The fringe claim is that these images show no evidence of gravitational tidal forces, nor gravitational lensing.
I'd like to read some proper research, explaining what we are supposed to be looking at.

Answer (score 7):

It's [infrared optical interferometry with ESO's Very Large Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Telescope#Interferometry) at the Paranal Observatory.

Have a look at [How did they make a video of the center of the galaxy, and what is it exactly that's flashing there?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28940/7982) (GIF) and [ESOcast 173: First Successful Test of Einstein’s General Relativity Near Supermassive Black Hole](https://youtu.be/if2opecmev8) (video).

[This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28942/7982) explains further.

[image]

Screenshots from video, click for full size:

[image: ESOcast 173 screenshot] [image: ESOcast 173 screenshot]

Comment: That video is amazing. Tax money well spent. (Pierson's Puppeteers will pay top galacto-dollar for this.) Eagerly awaiting the results of the attempt to image Sagittarius A* directly.

Answer (score 6):

These are the stellar orbits around Sagittarius A$^*$. The original work and a discussion is available on the Arxiv as the paper [Stellar Orbits Near Sagittarius A$^*$](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0201031) by Eckart, Genzel, Ott and Schoedel. This paper is from 2002 to there have been another seventeen years of observation since. The animation you describe was presumably done using all the recent data. Offhand I don't know where the very latest data can be downloaded. A quick Google failed to locate it but I imagine it's not beyond a more determined search.